# what does WTX (websphere transformation extender)

Tags: wtx

I'm not finding a lot of information on the internet about what is and what does WTX.

Can you give me some lights about it, and give me an example?

Also, the EAI BizTalk Server from microsoft is related to wtx?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WTX is a data transformation tool, for exmaple it will transform CSV into XML, one flavour of XML (e.g. RosettaNet) into another (e.g. an application format) etc.

It is owned and developed by [IBM](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/wdatastagetx).

Transformations are referred to as **maps** and are built by dragging and dropping fields in the Eclipse based design tool.

The WTX runtime engine can be called in a variety of ways - e.g. through the Java API, the TX Launcher, IBM Integration Bus, etc.

WTX has been previously known as **Mercator** and **DataStage TX**

EAI BizTalk Server is also a tool for integrating applications and transforming data. I'm not aware of any adapters between the two tools, but you could develop one using the WTX API.

Answer (score 3):

- **WTX** is the one of the powerful data transformation tool present in the integration industry .
- Generally **XML** data transformation is done in may ways like **XSLT** ect . but when it comes to `EDI` , stander Messages like `EDFACT ASCII` transformation logic will be very difficult in other tools .
- `WTX` can easily handle these type of transformation and its very flexible tool for transformation for any type of message.
- EX: Lets consider two systems communicating and system A send data in `IDOC` , systmem B wants in `XML` . You can use a **WTX** map in between and achieve this . Also you can handle business rules in **WTX**.